# Realm query with limit

Tags: android, realm

In Realm android there is a way to get List from Table within a Tight Bound. That is like :

```
select * from POST where id<50 AND id>10
```

Its Realm representation is :

```
realm.where(Post.class)
     .greaterThanOrEqualTo("id", 10)
     .lessThan("id", 50)
     .findAllSorted("id", false);
```

Here limit 10-50 may contains 40 row cause "id" is auto-increment primary key.

Now my concern is how can add a LIMIT on this realm Query? My query will like this :

```
select * from POST where id<50 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Related Links:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873402/how-can-i-set-limit-in-query-in-realm) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291237/how-to-get-number-of-records-using-limit-query-in-realm-database-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852573/limit-realm-results)

Comment: Please note that while a LIMIT enhancement is under consideration, it buys you almost nothing, in Realm.  In the SQL case, it is an effective way of controlling both memory and time to load.  In Realm, all of the data iis *already in memory*.  The query simply creates a reference to it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `List.subList` method:

e.g., `list.subList(0, 15)`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is realm directly provide any method to do this?

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim , as i know, no. You can read this github thread: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/544

Comment: As @Vyacheslav points out, `LIMIT` is not supported. In SQL, you use `LIMIT` to limited how much you load from your database (you copy rows from disk to memory to application). Realm is zero-copy so you don't see the same memory pressure.

Comment: @geisshirt yes. if you read the link hte in comment you will see the same. I the topic starter needs only a part of this array, he can do what I wrote.

Comment: I am fully aware of the contents of the issue :-) The reason we haven't implemented functionality as `LIMIT` is that a `RealmResults` isn't as heavy as it sounds.